# Right way to implement click on recycleView's row - passing the model itself

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I read some answers on stackOverflow about how to implement clicks on a recycleView row and ended up with this version:

ViewHolder:

```
public class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final TextView text_name;
    private final IContactClick listener;

    public ContactViewHolder(View itemView, IContactClick _listener) {
        super(itemView);

        text_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
        listener = _listener;
    }

    public void bind(final Contact model) {
        text_name.setText(model.name);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.contactClick(model);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface IContactClick {
        void contactClick(Contact contact);
    }
}
```

Adaptar:

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactViewHolder> implements ContactViewHolder.IContactClick{

private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private final List<Contact> mModels;

public ContactsAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> models) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mModels = new ArrayList<>(models);
}

public void contactClick(Contact contact) {
    Log.d("contactClick", contact.name);
}
...
```

I had to change the model to final so I can use it within the callback. This seems to work. I wonder whether this is a good practice before moving on.

Cheers

Comment: There is no issue continuing . You need to declare it final cuz it is assessed from inner class.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with `RecyclerView`, but I think this approach applies to `ListView` as well. I implement my `ListAdapter`s this way because somehow it gives a sense of decoupling. For example, if you want to use the same `Adapter` in more than one `ListView` / `RecyclerView` (with same row views / but different click behaviors for example), this approach lets you do that.

PS: I am yet to find one use case for the above configuration, yet I like to think that the decoupling will give me advantage.

Regarding your concern about the passing model itself (and thus making it final), I don't think that is ever a problem. I have had many `ListView`s implemented that way. Though if you have a simple `RecyclerView` you can pass `position` to your click handler and in `Fragment` / `Activity` you can call `Adapter#getItem(position)` to get the model.